# I want to call mex file

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I have `mex` wrappers to Fortran codes. I want to call those `mex` functions in Matlab in Windows 64-bit computer. So the question is: do I need to setup Fortran compiler with the Matlab to just call the `mex` functions? Or, would it be as simple as calling the function as any Matlab function? the latter didn't work.

Comment: It's not clear what you have, i.e., what you mean by "mex wrappers to FORTRAN codes". Do you have FORTRAN source code or compiled functions?

Comment: What you mean by it didn't work. Be specific, what exactly did you try? Of course you need a Fortran (not FORTRAN for some 25 years) compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to "just [call the mex functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html)" FORTRAN source code (files with a `.F` extension) needs to be compiled into an executable for your computer's architecture. For Windows-64bit, the resultant files will likely have a file extension of either `.mexa64` (AMD-64) or `.mexw64` (Intel-64). Type [`mexext`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexext.html) in your command window if you are unsure of what kind of CPU you have.